# How to yield an object provided by fixture with autouse=True?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there some way to get a yielded object from autouse fixture without explicitly providing it as an input argument in a test function?

Say, I have something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def setup_something():
    something = Something()
    something.do_something(thing=1)
    yield something
```

Then, when I want to access this object, I do this:

```
def test_scenario(self):
    something.do_something_else()
```

The reason for that is one might have a lot of setup/teardown fixtures which provide some object or do other stuff, and mentioning all of them as parameters might be too cumbersome.

Comment: Why would you not mention the fixture as a test function argument if you are gonna be working with what it yields? After all how is the yielded object supposed to appear in the function?

Comment: @tmt I think it is somewhat mentioned in the last part, but I was wondering if there is some way not to mention all the fixtures which yield an object AND valid for use in every function (the reason for autouse). There might be 5, 10 or more fixtures and when denoting all of them, the signature may become well too difficult to read, let alone understand.

Comment: But are you going to be working with all the fixtures in the function? You can still autouse a fixture and it would be called even when you don't mention it as a test function attribute, you just cannot work with what it yields and is more suitable for pure setup/teardown. There is an option for grouping the tests in a class and having the fixture set a class/instance attribute that the test methods can access but I think it would be a mess if the tests were run in parallel.

Comment: If talking about running in parallel, I completely agree. Though that's not the case here :p 
Yeah, I think something like class attribute can work. It's pretty sad that pytest does not provide that as an option

Comment: I think that pytest is very flexible and my answer shows how to do it. It''s just that IMHO it goes against the concept of dependency injection of fixtures which is what makes pytest beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

You could set an attribute of a test class instance but I'm far from sure that it would be a good idea.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def something(request):
    request.instance.something = Something()
    request.instance.something.do_something(thing=1)
    yield request.instance.something

class Test:
    def test_scenario(self):
        self.something.do_something_else()
```